# MongoKitten : Find using contains

Tags: swift, mongokitten

I have started using MongoKitten (Swift) which is really nice, however, I can't find anywhere how to do a Mongo find looking for a partial string.

In Mongo, it would be:

> db.users.findOne({"username" : {$regex : ".son."}});

Seems such a normal thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

So after talking to the MongoKitten people on Slack I thought I would come back and answer the question.  Code for Swift 4

```
func findDocsWith( str: String) -> CollectionSlice<Document>? {

    do {
        let server = try Server(Settings.server)
        let database = server["YourDB"]
        let pages = database["YourCollection"]


        let query: Query = [
            "url": RegularExpression(pattern: ".\(str).")
        ]

        let matchingEntities: CollectionSlice<Document> = try pages.find(query)
        print (try matchingEntities.count())

        return matchingEntities

    } catch {
        print("error: unable to start rest service.\n")

        return nil
    }
```

}